# wglGetCurrentDC unresolved external

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opencl

I guess I've been driven into a thunder for this kind of problem. I'm using visual studio 2015 community with qt5.6.0 (msvc2015_64) in order to make a QOpenglWidget to demonstrate a result calculated by devices using OpenCL.

Now I'm blind creating a context using the function "wglGetCurrentContext" and "wglGetCurrentDC", the error are:

"LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _imp_wglGetCurrentContext referenced in function "protected: void _cdecl VolRenGL::createCLContext(int,char const* *)" (?createCLContext@VolRenGL@IEAAXHPEAPEBD@Z)"
"LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _imp_wglGetCurrentDC referenced in function "protected: void _cdecl VolRenGL::createCLContext(int,char const* *)" (?createCLContext@VolRenGL@@IEAAXHPEAPEBD@Z)"

Related code:

```
cl_context_properties props[] =
        {
            CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
            CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)cpPlatform,
            0
        };
        cxGPUContext = clCreateContext(props, 1, &cdDevices[uiDeviceUsed], NULL, NULL, &err);
```

Comment: If you're using QOpenGLWidget, you shouldn't create OpenGL context: the widget is doing it for you. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: OP tries to create a OpenCL context with OpenGL interop. The only way to do this is to get a handle to the native platform GL context, which that `wglGetCurrentDC` is for.

Answer (score 3):

Stupid question, but do you link *your* program with `opengl32.lib/dll`? In Windows the symbols linked into DLLs don't "leak", so you've to link to the right libraries. Qt hides that problem by also providing a OpenGL loader so if you write a fully idiomatic Qt OpenGL program you can do so without actually linking explicitly against `opengl32.lib/dll`

Comment: Remain unresolved after selected the path and pragmaed the lib.